# When user redirect to website after payment gateway all session data gets lost, we are using ASP.NET webform .NET 4.8 Framework

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, asp.net-session

We have an e-commerce website where a user places an order. Earlier it was working very smoothly, but since a few updates from chrome, when the user redirects to website after payment gateway, all session data is lost.

We are using ASP.NET webforms on the .NET 4.8 Framework. Can you please help us solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Since Chrome 79 session "lost" after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826498/since-chrome-79-session-lost-after-redirect)